How can I copy large output without showing it all?
I want to copy some cell as 'Cell Expression', more precisely, by using 'Edit -> Copy As -> Cell Expression'.
However, whenever I try to do this for large output, I first need to click 'show all', and then I can copy it correctly. The problem is that whenever I tries to show them all, it takes a huge amout of time to wait. How can I bypass this issue?
Thank you.

You can do Cell[ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ yourInputCode, "Output"] for Cell Expression. Is that what you are after?

@Kuba and you can use CopyToClipboard@Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes[Range[10^5]], "Output"]; to directly get it into your clipboard. (Using Range[10^5] as a generic example of something that produces large output).

Maybe you can use Iconize to get a compact output, and then copy the output instead, like Range[10^5] // Iconize and then copy the icon as the output.
